# How do I return a class-based view method with super from a function within that very same class-based view method?

Tags: django

Is it even possible?

I can't find anything or figure it out by myself since I'm a beginner, so I turn to you guys.

Here's an example (don't worry about the use case, I just want to know if it's possible and how):

When I run this code I get that *args is not defined. What's wrong?

views.py:

```py
class MyCreateView(CreateView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      slug = kwargs['slug']
      helper_method(self, slug)
```

helpers.py:

```py
def helper_method(self, slug):
   if slug == "random":
      return super(self.__class__, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `args` and `kwargs`, you just need to add them to your method parameters like this:

```
def helper_method(self, slug, *args, **kwargs):
   if slug == "random":
      return super(self.__class__, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      slug = kwargs['slug']
      helper_method(self, slug, *args, **kwargs)
```